# Entity Framework Core 2.x Update Dbset not working

Tags: ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have tried

```
dbSet.Update(_member)
```

which duplicates the entry, and

```
dbSet.Attach(_member)
```

which ends up in an exception.

In EF Core 1.6, it works without any issue, I had created an extension for `AddOrUpdate` which works fine in 1.6, but not in 2.x

Comment: There are definitely changes in `Update` behavior between 1.x and 2.x which might break an existing working code. You can take a look at [Disconnected entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities)  documentation section, which discusses different add or update strategies.

Comment: Please tell us ***WHAT*** error you're getting - remember: we cannot read your screen, nor your mind - you 'll have to **SHOW US** so we have any chance at all of helping you !!